# Bootstrap modal UncaughtType Error on modal loading

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, typeerror

I am using BS modal in my project. I am using a button to open the model but as I open the modal I get this error in my console.

Error:

```
modal.js:418 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hide')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:418:23)
    at HTMLDocument.s (event-handler.js:119:21)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card my-2 mx-2 mt-4" style="width: 18rem;">
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#mymodal" data-bs-toggle="modal"  
style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0">Get Quote</button>
</div>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
DO SOMETHING
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap5 CDNs:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please add modal.js code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be a bug in Bootstrap5 but I solved by adding the `fade` class to the `modal`.

Here's how I did it.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                DO SOMETHING
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: similar.. but in my case I had 3 modals, one of which had class="modal fade show". I removed the 'show' class and it solved the issue

Comment: removing the `show` class worked for me.

Comment: ` class="modal fade show"` that was my case too.

Answer (score 0):

fade class doent work for me.

I'm using WebpackEncore bundle 1.15.1 and bootstrap 5.2.

I had to downgrade bootstrap to 5.1 version to work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32297789)

Comment: I'm not asking nothing, juste propose to downgrade to 5.1 ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was another open modal but not visible because of custom styles. After fixing it worked.